# Software or Tricks For Live Coding Presentation

Tags: powerpoint, presentation, keynote, livecoding

I am going to be giving an intro presentation / training class on Ruby on Rails soon.  I would like to make it interesting and engaging while still seeming "polished".  Since it's a hands-on class most people will be building an app along with me, I want to be able to show my terminal/editor and show the resulting web pages, however I'd like to not be always switching between windows.  Keynote used to have the ability to embed webpages into slides, but it was removed, and PowerPoint Mac support seems iffy.  There doesn't seem to be any way to embed a terminal window.

Does anyone have a recommendation for presentation software that might be able to help?  Have you seen a good live coding talk recently that I could check out?  Are there any tricks that you know that make your presentation seem more "professional"?

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I didn't realize.  What about questions that have not been adequately answered?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [CodeDemo](http://www.codedemo.net/). It is designed to assist with live coding during presentations - http://www.codedemo.net/

Answer (score 0):

if you're specifically looking for embedding webpages in slides, have a look at [reveal.js](https://revealjs.com/), which apparently allows embedding arbitrary iframes.