# replaying code for a hands on code presentation

Tags: git, intellij-idea, presentation, livecoding

So I need to conduct a workshop where I will be coding live on stage to build a demo app while the audience may follow.

First problem is my typing speed is slow and secondly we have a fixed time span in which to complete the presentation.

I have seen some youtube videos where presenters will use some magic keys and full lines will appear in the IDE without typing or they mock the typing but at a super fast speed. A big time saver.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441342/software-or-tricks-for-live-coding-presentation) similar question but that tool works only on windows and I am on a mac.

Another similar concept is implemented on [thecodeplayer](http://thecodeplayer.com/).

My best bet right now is to save each step into a git branch and keep checking out the branches as I go during the presentation.

Any better ideas? maybe even a shell script that can checkout next branch in a chronological order ? or does there exist any tool for this purpose?

EDIT: I am using IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE, just in case there is a plugin for such use cases.

EDIT2: Some other tools doing similar stuff

[doitlive](https://doitlive.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

[playerpiano](https://pypi.org/project/PlayerPiano/)

[hackertyper](http://hackertyper.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) feature of IntelliJ. You may have used it before, for example the most known one is when you type

```
sout
```

and then you see dropdown of options, if you hit Enter it will become

```
System.out.println()
```

So what you need to do is to create a several of those for your presentation. Here is an IntelliJ [page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-live-templates.html) on how to do it. Note that you can place cursor inside of a created code block, so if, for example, you want to create a method, with one template you can create an empty method, then second template will print the method body, and so on.